# How can i get all combinations for 2 Matrices. Both have numerical values

Tags: excel, excel-formula, combinations

I have 2 Matrices. For ease lets consider this

Matrix 1:

10     20
20     40

Matrix 2:

40     80
50     100

I want an output of all combinations:

400, 800, 500, 1000
800,1600,1000,2000
800,1600,1000,2000
1600,3200,2000,4000

Is there any way in which I can set this up on Excel?

Answer (score 0):

This formula solution required Office 365 for the using of TEXTJOIN function

In range `A1:D1` enter : 10,20,20,40

and in range `A2:D2` enter : 40,80,50,100

Then in `F1`, enter array (CSE) formula :

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",1,A2*A1:D1&","&B2*A1:D1&","&C2*A1:D1&","&D2*A1:D1)
```

`F2`, will give the desired result :

```
400,800,500,1000,800,1600,1000,2000,800,1600,1000,2000,1600,3200,2000,4000
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the two matrices are in columns and everything starts in row 2, you can create a 2d array of their products and extract the results in order using Index:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(A$2:A$5*TRANSPOSE(B$2:B$5),INT((ROW()-2)/ROWS(B$2:B$5))+1,MOD(ROW()-2,ROWS(B$2:B$5))+1),"")
```

This is an array formula and must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

[image]